# POST Request TypeError - Cannot Read Property of Undefined

Tags: node.js, express, curl

I'm sending a curl request to my mongo server and the request keeps saying "Cannot read property 'username' of undefined". My best guess is that my curl request isn't formatted correctly, which would explain the undefined request but it looks fine to me. Can anyone see what the problem is here?

Curl Request:

```
curl "http://localhost:3000/api/users" \
  --include \
  --request POST \
  --data '{
    "user": {
        "username": "testuser",
        "email": "test@email.com",
        "pwd": "pass"
    }
}'
```

User Routes:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const User = require('../models/user')
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.user.username,
    email: req.body.user.email,
    passhash: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.user.pwd, 10)
  })
  user.save().then(
    (newuser) => {
      res.json({
        user: newuser,
        message: 'success'
      })enter code here
    },
    (err) => {
      res.send(500, 'Error is: ' + err.message)
    }
  )
})
module.exports = router
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been banging my head against the wall for the past two hours trying to figure this out.

Also here's my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})

app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'))

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('app is listening on port 3000...')
})
```

I just wanted to post this to illustrate that I'm using the bodyParser

Comment: How about `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{ "user": { "username": "testuser", "email": "test@email.com", "pwd": "pass" } }' http://localhost:3000/api/users` Reordering arguments and setting the Content-Type

Comment: This worked like charm! thhank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `Content-Type` header in your request. Without it, the server does not know how the request body should be interpreted. Specifically in this particular case, the `Content-Type` should probably be application/json.

Comment: oh my god I cant believe i forgot to set the flippin content type. thank you!!